# Pinning a document to a SharePoint Home Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document, shortcut

I'm trying to find out if a document can be pinned for quick access to the home page of a SharePoint folder structure rather than just in the hosting folder - some of my colleagues are struggling to find documents.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Sussed it for anyone else looking:

- Right-click or tick the target document and pick 'copy link'
- Move to home page/root page in SharePoint, right-click and select 'New>Link',  then select that link and 'Pin to top' of the page....

Voila! Home page link to buried document and no more challenged colleagues!